# How can I get my project's folder structure to be mirrored in Finder?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode (4.2) project with a bunch of class files, and I have them neatly organized into folders. These folder aren't "real", however; in Finder, my classes are all just dumped into the one "Classes" folder. Is there any way to get the virtual folder structure I see in Xcode to be reflected in the real Finder folder structure? Or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/venmo/synx

A command-line tool that reorganizes your Xcode project folder to match your Xcode groups

**Installation**

$ gem install synx

**Usage**

**Basic**

:warning: WARNING: Make sure that your project is backed up through source control before doing anything :warning:

Execute the command on your project to have it reorganize the files on the file system:

$ synx path/to/my/project.xcodeproj

It may have confused CocoaPods. If you use them, execute this command:

$ pod install

You're good to go!

**Advanced**

Synx supports the following options:

--prune, -p                   remove source files and image resources that are not referenced by the the Xcode project

--no-color                    removes all color from the output

--no-default-exclusions       doesn't use the default exclusions of /Libraries, /Frameworks, and /Products

--quiet, -q                   silence all output

--exclusion, -e EXCLUSION     ignore an Xcode group while syncing

For example, OCMock could have been organized using this command:

$ synx -p -e "/OCMock/Core Mocks" -e /OCMockTests Source/OCMock.xcodeproj/

if they had wanted not to sync the /OCMock/Core Mocks and /OCMockTests groups, and also remove (-p) any image/source files found by synx that weren't referenced by any groups in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I often want to do the same thing, but as far as I know there is no automatic way to do it, you have to do it manually unfortunately...

Comment: Is there a good reason for me to not get angry at how stupid this is? File organization is a pretty important thing in an IDE.

Comment: its important _in_ an IDE, which XCode has, why do you want it outside of the IDE, where you most likely wont be modifying any files?

Comment: @MusiGenesis I don't think so, I agree it should do it automatically.

Comment: @wattson12 Because sh... happens. In fact, with Xcode, the more the files you have in the workspace, the more likely it gets that bad stuff is going to happen. Tell me with a straight face you never had to go fix by hand (finder, sh) something that Xcode mangled bad. Late reply : i was about to ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'automatic' way to make the XCode file pane structure automagically conform to the finder folder structure, although I agree there should be a setting for this.

I follow these steps when making a project:

1. Create the project.
2. Delete by reference any files I want to move.
3. Open finder and move the files, then drag them back into XCode.

When adding new files:

1. Create a folder in finder if needed.
2. Drag the folder into XCode.
3. Right-click and make a new file on the group that represents the folder just dragged in.

If you're using git, it's a little more work:

1. Commit your project before making a folder or file deletions/moves.
2. Delete them by reference from XCode.
3. Move them in finder.
4. Using terminal, type `git mv sourcePath destPath` to move files or `git rm sourcePath` to delete them.
5. Then drag back into XCode.

You can see more about my frustration with learning git here:
[How can I move files & folders using git in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193796/how-can-i-move-files-folders-using-git-in-xcode-4/)