# How can I move files & folders using git in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, git, xcode4

I'm familiar with the differences between groups and actual directories in Xcode.  I always create an actual folder in finder and drag it into the project, ensuring 'copy' is un-checked.

When I move folders, I delete the items by reference only, move them in finder, then re-add them.

Now I'm using git for the first time, and discovered in my testing that if I remove a directory using the method described above, I can't do a commit.  Xcode tells me it can't switch to the directory because 'no such file or directory.'  From what I've found online, git isn't notified of the directory changes when done in Xcode.

How can I move files & folders using git in Xcode 4 and have the compiler and git be aware of the moves so I can commit?

Comment: Are you familiar with using the git command-line client at all?

Comment: No, not really.  I do have the book 'Pro Git' but I'm worried that if I remove files from the git repository in terminal that it will screw up the files in Xcode (meaning the way xcode keeps track of it's own files).

Comment: I was just going to suggest running `git add --all` on your repository then resume your Xcode management.

Comment: What if I want to delete an existing folder, then re-add the folder in another location? (In effect, moving the folder)  What will happen when the folder is missing?  If you could describe the steps to do this in an answer post I will test it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving Files into a Real Folder in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414181/moving-files-into-a-real-folder-in-xcode)

Answer (score 5):

You shall not move files in a GIT repository using the Finder. You'd better use the move command from shell.

You then have to manually redresh links in XCode (or remove/add files again).

Moving a file is similar to the unix 'mv' command, with the 'git prefix:

`git mv path destination`

(use -f to override destination... with caution)

Comment: "You shall not move files in a GIT repository using the Finder."  Why?  Can you edit your answer and show the 'proper' steps to delete (and move if possible)?  I'm not a command line junkie, so if you could add them along with your steps it would be very helpful for me and other S.O. users.

Comment: Have a look to http://jonas.nitro.dk/git/quick-reference.html

You may also use a graphical UI for GIT. I don't, so I cannot give any advice for this.

Comment: So I would have to do this for each file or folder that is moved?

Comment: I think so. Unless you can automate things in XCode. If you feel confortable you may want to edit the project XML file directly, but I would not recomend this unless your're an expert :)

Answer (score 4):

After you have made all your changes in the Finder, open a terminal window and navigate to your project's directory:

```
cd path/to/project
```

then run this command:

```
git add --all
```

This command will stage all of the changes and Xcode should be able to resume its management of the repository from here.

Comment: I tested it and it works. A question about it though.  The file I removed in xcode and then moved in finder.  Does Git think the file at the old position is still there or does it simply 'figure out' that it was moved?  If so, does this work with resources with the same names but different locations (such as localized folders)?

Comment: @Javy Git is very clever in these scenarios; it can usually work out that a file has been moved & renamed even if it's been modified. That's why it's better than subversion ;)

Comment: I want to believe in the power of git.  Sadly, I can't.  After having a big project get screwed up royally and re-creating the entire thing, I tried again on a smaller project.  Now when I modify a folder, I try to rm it and it fails, saying it doesn't exist, but XCode says it does.  So I use your recommendation to add all and it really wants to add everything, including the files in gitignore.  I can't fathom why there are no effective tutorials on git for XCode users. I think I'm going to ditch git until I find a good tutorial.  :/

Comment: @Javy My advice: don't use Xcode, just use the terminal; it's much easier.